# Display that fits with parameters

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

I have made database that contains some information. Want to do is to retrieve and display data that fits with parameters like:

if i select green from dropdown list, it will display only information about cars that are green. Also "kõik" means like all.

Here is form that im using.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body align="center" style="margin-top:200px;">
<table border="1" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td>   
<form  action="retrieve.php" method="get">
Rass:
<select name="rass"> 
<option value="ebony">Ebony</option> 
<option value="Valge">Valge</option> 
<option value="Aasia">Aasia</option> 
</select> <br />
<input type="submit" value="lisa" />
</form>    
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is php that used to show all data.

```
<?php

$connect = @mysql_connect ("localhost", "root", "") or die("Fail!!!! :D:D:D");
mysql_select_db("tibid") or die("selline andmebaas puudub");

$query = mysql_query("select * from test"); 
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query);

if($num_rows > 0){
{while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))

    echo 
    $row['rinnad']. "<br>"
    .$row['juuksed']."<br>"
    .$row['silmad']."<br>"
    .$row['rass']."<br>
    <hr>
    ";}
}else{ 
echo "Andmebaas on tühi";

}

?>
```

Link to this kind tutorial would be helpful.
Thank you

Comment: What is your question exactly? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for `WHERE`. So your query would be:

```
select * from cars where color = '$color'
```

where `$color` is [escaped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php) `$_POST['color']` passed from your form.

Comment: Yep. Updated with link how to prevent injections.